# How can I count the number of list items for each unordered list in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to get the number of the list items `li` for every unordered list with the same class but I want the number separately for every list. I have tried the code below and I get the number from all lists

```css
$(function(){
  var filterListMenu = $('.category-menu');
  var filterListMenuSize = filterListMenu.length;
  var count = $(".sidebar").find("ul").children().length;
  console.log('inner page lenghth: ' + count);
});
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <ul class="category-menu">
        <li>First Ul li1 </li>
        <li>First Ul li2 </li>
        <li>First Ul li3 </li>
        <li>First Ul li4</li>
        <li>First Ul li5</li>
        <li>First Ul li6</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="category-menu">
        <li>Second Ul li1 </li>
        <li>Second Ul li2 </li>
        <li>Second Ul li3 </li>
        <li>Second Ul li4</li>
        <li>Second Ul li5</li>
        <li>Second Ul li6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it any `.category-menu`? or any `ul` in `.sidebar`? You seem to use both and depending on the rest of your page they may not select exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of `li` within each `ul` you would need to loop through them. This can be done using `each()`:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var $filterListMenu = $('.category-menu');
  var filterListMenuSize = $filterListMenu.length;

  $filterListMenu.each((i, el) => {
    let count = $(el).children('li').length;
    console.log('inner page length: ' + count);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="category-menu">
    <li>First Ul li1 </li>
    <li>First Ul li2 </li>
    <li>First Ul li3 </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="category-menu">
    <li>Second Ul li1 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li2 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li3 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li4</li>
    <li>Second Ul li5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use `map()` to build a single array containing the lengths of all `ul` in the DOM:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var counts = $('.category-menu').map((i, el) => $(el).children('li').length).get();
  console.log(counts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="category-menu">
    <li>First Ul li1 </li>
    <li>First Ul li2 </li>
    <li>First Ul li3 </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="category-menu">
    <li>Second Ul li1 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li2 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li3 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li4</li>
    <li>Second Ul li5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is as follows:

```js
// selecting the elements, and then chaining with
// the after() method, to insert an element after
// the current element(s):
$('ul.category-menu').after(function(i,e){
  // here we find the number of <li> elements
  // in the current <ul> element:
  let count = $(this).find('li').length,
      // creating a new <span> element to
      // contain the count:
      span = $('<span />', {
        // setting the count as the text of
        // the <span>:
        text: count,
      });
  // returning the <span> to the after() method
  // for insertion into the document:
  return span;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="category-menu">
    <li>First Ul li1 </li>
    <li>First Ul li2 </li>
    <li>First Ul li3 </li>
    <li>First Ul li4</li>
    <li>First Ul li5</li>
    <li>First Ul li6</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="category-menu">
    <li>Second Ul li1 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li2 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li3 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li4</li>
    <li>Second Ul li5</li>
    <li>Second Ul li6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In plain JavaScript – everything possible in jQuery is possible in plain JavaScript – this could be achieved with:

```js
// here we select all <ul> elements with the class-name
// of 'category-menu', and we iterate over those elements
// using NodeList.prototype.forEach(), along with an
// Arrow function:
document.querySelectorAll('ul.category-menu').forEach(
  // here we pass in a reference to the current
  // element:
  (element) => {
    // we create a <span> element to contain the
    // counter:
    let span = document.createElement('span'),
        // we retrieve the number of <li> children
        // (<li> is the only element that is a
        // valid child-element of a <ul> or <ol>):
        count = element.children.length;

    // we set the text-content of the <span>:
    span.textContent = `Count: ${count}`;

    // and use ParentNode.insertBefore to insert
    // the new <span> into the document after
    // the current <ul>; we navigate to the
    // current element's parentNode, and use
    // insertBefore() to insert:
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(
      // the <span>, before:
      span,
      // the current <ul> element's next element
      // sibling (if there is no next element
      // sibling this does not generate an error):
      element.nextElementSibling);
});
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="category-menu">
    <li>First Ul li1 </li>
    <li>First Ul li2 </li>
    <li>First Ul li3 </li>
    <li>First Ul li4</li>
    <li>First Ul li5</li>
    <li>First Ul li6</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="category-menu">
    <li>Second Ul li1 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li2 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li3 </li>
    <li>Second Ul li4</li>
    <li>Second Ul li5</li>
    <li>Second Ul li6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or, without JavaScript, CSS would allow:

```css
/* here we increment a named counter in each
   <li> element within the <ul> of the
   'category-menu' class: */
ul.category-menu li {
  counter-increment: listCount;
}

/* here we use the ::after pseudo-element of
   each <ul> element of the 'category-menu'
   class, using the counter() function to
   specify which counter should be used and
   and the form of that counter: */
ul.category-menu::after {
  content: 'Count: ' counter(listCount, decimal);
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <ul class="category-menu">
        <li>First Ul li1 </li>
        <li>First Ul li2 </li>
        <li>First Ul li3 </li>
        <li>First Ul li4</li>
        <li>First Ul li5</li>
        <li>First Ul li6</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="category-menu">
        <li>Second Ul li1 </li>
        <li>Second Ul li2 </li>
        <li>Second Ul li3 </li>
        <li>Second Ul li4</li>
        <li>Second Ul li5</li>
        <li>Second Ul li6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice, I'd not heard of `counter` in CSS before, thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery.map to return an array of the lengths:

```
const lengths = $('.category-menu').map((_, el) => $('li', el).length).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use each to loop all  elements then count the lengh of each of them, finally store in an array.

```
var arr = []
$('.sidebar').find('ul').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).find('li').length);
});
```